# assign ggplot2 geom attributes to variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first question on stackoverflow so please correct me if the question is unclear.

I would like to assign geom attributes for ggplot2 to a variable for reuse in multiple plots. For example, let's say I want to assign the attributes of size and shape to a variable to resuse in plotting data other than mtcars.

This code works, but if I have a lot of plots I don't want to keep re-entering the size and shape attributes.

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt, 
             y = mpg),
         size = 5,
         shape = 21
         )
```

How should I assign a variable (eg size.shape) these attributes so that I can use it in the below code to produce the same plot?

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = wt,
             y = mpg),
         size.shape
         )
```

Comment: You could do `size.shape <- list(size = 5, shape = 21); ggplot(mtcars) + do.call(geom_point, c(list(aes(x = wt, y = mpg)), size.shape))`.

Comment: might be a good use-case for `aes_string()`

Comment: Thanks guys! do.call and Stibu's answer on changing the defaults permits solving the problem in a variety of ways. Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to use the same values for `size` and `shape` (or other aesthetics), you could use `update_geom_defaults()` to set the default values to other values:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(size = 5, shape = 21))
```

These will then be used whenever you do not specifically give values for the aesthetics.

### Example

The plot you create with the usual default settings looks as follows:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg))
```

[image]

But when you reset the defaults for `size` and `shape`, it looks differently:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(size = 5, shape = 21))
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg))
```

[image]

As you can see, the actual plot is done with the same code as before, but the result is different because you changed the default values for `size` and `shape`. Of course, you can still produce plots with any value for these aesthetics, by simply providing values in `geom_point()`:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg), size = 2, shape = 2)
```

[image]

Note that the defaults are given by `geom`, which means that only `geom_point()` is affected.

This solution is convenient, if there is only one set of values for `size` and `shape` that you want to use. If you have several sets of values that you want to be able to pick from when creating a plot, then you might be better off with something along the lines of the comment by [lukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea).

Comment: Thanks Stibu! This is really going to come in handy! I tried to give it an upvote, but I'm so new I don't have enough reputation points yet. Until then, Thanks!